# SQL: Merge data from 2 tables for each id

Tags: sql-server

I want to merge two tables but multiple times i.e. for each value in the first table.
Is there a simple SQL statement to do this? Union/loop?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

#### Data

```
DECLARE @T1 table 
(
    id integer NOT NULL, 
    [value] integer NOT NULL, 
    prio integer NOT NULL, 
    article integer NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @T2 table 
(
    id integer NOT NULL, 
    [value] integer NOT NULL, 
    prio integer NOT NULL, 
    article integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T1
    (id, [value], prio, article)
VALUES
    (33, 12, 1, 123),
    (33, 34, 3, 123),
    (33, 56, 5, 123);

INSERT @T2
    (id, [value], prio, article)
VALUES
    (33, 99, 4, 123),
    (33, 99, 8, 123),
    (33, 99, 10, 123);
```

#### Solution

```
SELECT
    Result.id, 
    Result.[value], 
    Result.prio, 
    Result.article,
    merge_id = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T1.prio)
FROM @T1 AS T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT Ord = 1, T1.*
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Ord = 2, T2.*
    FROM @T2 AS T2
) AS Result
ORDER BY
    merge_id, Result.Ord, Result.prio;
```

#### Results

| id | value | prio | article | merge_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 12 | 1 | 123 | 1 |
| 33 | 99 | 4 | 123 | 1 |
| 33 | 99 | 8 | 123 | 1 |
| 33 | 99 | 10 | 123 | 1 |
| 33 | 34 | 3 | 123 | 2 |
| 33 | 99 | 4 | 123 | 2 |
| 33 | 99 | 8 | 123 | 2 |
| 33 | 99 | 10 | 123 | 2 |
| 33 | 56 | 5 | 123 | 3 |
| 33 | 99 | 4 | 123 | 3 |
| 33 | 99 | 8 | 123 | 3 |
| 33 | 99 | 10 | 123 | 3 |

Demo: [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/TOFTm-gw)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the cross product of the two tables. To accomplish this, you could use a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/) and then a `UNION ALL` like so:

```
-- Cross product of the two tables to multiply out the the second table
SELECT
    Table2.id,
    Table2.[value],
    Table2.prio,
    Table2.article,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER 
    (
        ORDER BY 
            Table1.id,
            Table1.[value],
            Table1.prio,
            Table1.article
    ) AS Merge_id
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2

UNION ALL

-- Table1 being unioned back to the final results
SELECT
    Table1.id,
    Table1.[value],
    Table1.prio,
    Table1.article,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER 
    (
        ORDER BY 
            Table1.id,
            Table1.[value],
            Table1.prio,
            Table1.article
    ) AS Merge_id
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Merge_id, id, [value], prio, article
```